# Automatically capitalise the first word in each sentence

Tags: pdftex, capitalization

I'm writing a report together with another person, and he often neglects to use a capital letter at the start of each sentence. Is it possible to get LaTeX to correct this automatically instead of doing so by hand?

Comment: "all the writhing in word" - I can't tell if that is a typo or not...

Comment: What do you mean by "no large literally"?

Comment: You no. After an dot the first letter is always capitalised. Latex dont handle this like word do.

Comment: Do you mean that your colleague just types things like "This is the first sentence. this is the second sentence." without paying attention to the capitalisation of the words, because he's used to Word automatically correcting that?

Comment: Yes i wont so the text stands correct like this:"This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence." not like this:"this is the first sentence. this is the second sentence.". Sorry it's an hard question to explain.

Comment: @mortenstarck, I'd search for something like: _LaTeX: automatically capitalize the first letter of the first word in a sentence_. The first hit on Google refers to a question on StackOverflow, might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818119/automatically-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-new-sentence-in-latex

Comment: If you happen to go with one of the answers provided in @Ailurus's link. Please go with the one that uses a script to change the input before compiling and not with the one that make the period active. That has the potential to break all kinds of stuff. Really, `\tikz\node at (0.5,0.5) {please don't};`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX is a set of macros for markup language TeX so definitely can't do anything. TeX maybe but [sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/) (AWK, TCL, Perl, Python, Ruby) is the right tool for the job.

Comment: I'd add that TeX *can* do this, but actually doing so is a bad idea.

Comment: TeX can do everything, but sometimes it can be easier to not use TeX.

Answer (score -1):

Borrowing this code would help you.

```
\let\period.
\catcode`\.\active 
\def\uppercasesingleletter#1{\uppercase{#1}}
\def.{\period\afterassignment\periodx\let\next= }
\def \periodx{\ifcat\space\next \next\expandafter\uppercasesingleletter \else\expandafter\next\fi}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you borrow some code, you should link to it's [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818990/7440933). Also there is an explanation of the code.